# JavaScript: Round to a number of decimal places, but strip extra zeros

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point, rounding

Here's the scenario: I'm getting `.9999999999999999` when I should be getting `1.0`.
I can afford to lose a decimal place of precision, so I'm using `.toFixed(15)`, which kind of works.

The rounding works, but the problem is that I'm given `1.000000000000000`.
**Is there a way to round to a number of decimal places, but strip extra whitespace?**

Note: `.toPrecision` isn't what I want; I only want to specify how many numbers after the decimal point.
Note 2: I can't just use `.toPrecision(1)` because I need to keep the high precision for numbers that actually have data after the decimal point. Ideally, there would be exactly as many decimal places as necessary (up to 15).

Comment: The point being that .toFixed returns a String, so just round-tripping it via a Number and then back to a String will reconvert it without the trailing zeros.

Comment: @Nathan: just for clarification. Do you just want to remove the trailing zeros in the *string* that you got with toFixed()?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

```
>>> parseFloat(0.9999999.toFixed(4));
1
>>> parseFloat(0.0009999999.toFixed(4));
0.001
>>> parseFloat(0.0000009999999.toFixed(4));
0
```

Comment: Don't forget to put them in parentheses when you treat negative numbers: `-2.34.toFixed(1)` returns `-2.3` due to the _operator precedence_.

Comment: Using the unary + operator should be faster than the `parseFloat` function: `+number.toFixed(13)` This expression can also be used to remove JavaScript number inaccuracies like in 1.0000000000000045.

Answer (score 42):

Yes, there is a way. Use `parseFloat()`.

```
parseFloat((1.005).toFixed(15)) //==> 1.005
parseFloat((1.000000000).toFixed(15)) //==> 1
```

See a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/7JBJw/

Comment: Doesn't work for `parseFloat("0.0000007")`, which gives `"7e-7"`

Answer (score 25):

As I understand, you want to remove the trailing zeros in the string that you obtained via `toFixed()`. This is a pure string operation:

```
var x = 1.1230000;
var y = x.toFixed(15).replace(/0+$/, "");  // ==> 1.123
```

Comment: You're the only one who really answered the question.. thanks!

Comment: This leaves the dot on round numbers ("100.00" => "100.")

Comment: @pckill if you don't want the dot you could include it in the regular expression to be replaced (`...replace(/\.?0+$/, "");`).

Comment: That fails on 0 and -0 because `0` becomes the empty string `""`, and `-0` becomes `-`, neither of which are expected (at a guess). @zach-snow your suggested solution also fails on 0 and -0.

Comment: @Mugen, what was the problem with Gus's answer?

Comment: @trysis I don't really remember as it was two years ago. But just for instance, Gus's answer rounded the number, and that was not the requested operation

Comment: @Mugen, if I am reading the question right, rounding the number is exactly what the OP wanted. He wanted to round to a certain amount of decimal places, which for some reason isn't possible with the built-in functions. This answer does the same thing.

Comment: @Mugen, I apologize, I am not trying to bash you or anything, just trying to understand why you thought this was the only proper answer, what pitfalls, etc. you found in the others. If you can remember, I would be grateful, but if not, it's no big deal.

Comment: @trysis [Gus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7312534/1899424) produces a floating point number. The OP asked for a string, which this answer produces.

Answer (score 14):

`Number(n.toFixed(15))  or +(n.toFixed(15))` will convert the 15 place decimal string to a number, removing trailing zeroes.

Comment: Thought I'd point it out, +(n.toFixed(...)) is much more efficient than parseFloat. Not sure why, but its also more efficient than Number in Chrome.

Answer (score 12):

If you cast the return value to a number, those trailing zeroes will be dropped. This is also less verbose than `parseFloat()` is.

```
+(4.55555).toFixed(2);
//-> 4.56

+(4).toFixed(2);
//-> 4
```

This uses the [unary + operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()), so if using this as part of a string operation you need to have an infix + before it: `var n=0.9999999999999999; console.log('output ' + +n.toFixed(2));`. FYI a unary + in front of a string converts it to a Number. From MDN: Unary + can:

> convert string representations of integers and floats, as well
>   as the non-string values true, false, and null. Integers in both
>   decimal and hexadecimal ("0x"-prefixed) formats are supported.
>   Negative numbers are supported (though not for hex). If it cannot
>   parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.

Comment: @robocat I've just done a simple check; `+(4.1).toFixed(4)` is `4.1` in _Chrome 60_.

Comment: I don't get it. What was the reason why this answer got downvoted?

Comment: @K You were right so I deleted my previous comment and added to the answer (I think I was using infix + with a string on lhs, rather than correctly using unary +. Usually I am more careful! Cheers)

Comment: This answer still works with NaN, Infinity, -Infinity, 3e30, and 0. Some other answers fail on some corner cases.

Comment: (4).toFixed(2) -> "4.00" in Chrome 60.0.3112.113

Comment: @DanielQue you need to use `+(4).toFixed(2)`. The unary + operator is critical as it strips the trailing zeros (while still treating Number corner-cases correctly). For example at the console try: `console.log('answer:' + +(4).toFixed(2));` prints `answer:4`.

Comment: [This is a fantastic resource about Number conversion](https://thecodebarbarian.com/convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-javascript.html) and the various corner cases - up to date and very detailed.

Answer (score 3):

None of these really got me what I was looking for based on the question title, which was, for example, for 5.00 to be 5 and 5.10 to be 5.1. My solution was as follows:

```
num.toFixed(places).replace(/\.?0+$/, '')

'5.00'.replace(/\.?0+$/, '') // 5
'5.10'.replace(/\.?0+$/, '') // 5.1
'5.0000001'.replace(/\.?0+$/, '') // 5.0000001
'5.0001000'.replace(/\.?0+$/, '') // 5.0001
```

Note: The regex only works if `places > 0`

P.S. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: Fails on `5e30` (changes number to `5e3`). Corner cases are diabolical!

Answer (score 1):

most efficient and bets method I found is below

```
function round(value, decimals) {
  return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better method which keeps precision and also strips the zeros. This takes an input number and through some magic of casting will pull off any trailing zeros. I've found 16 to be the precision limit for me which is pretty good should you not be putting a satellite on pluto.

```
function convertToFixed(inputnum)
{

      var mynum = inputnum.toPrecision(16);
//If you have a string already ignore this first line and change mynum.toString to the inputnum

      var mynumstr = mynum.toString();
    return parseFloat(mynumstr);
    }
    alert(convertToFixed(6.6/6));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`toFixed()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) formats a `number` using fixed-point notation, and returns a `string`.

It applies a **half-up rounding** strategy.

```
(0.124).toFixed(2); // returns 0.12
(0.125).toFixed(2); // returns 0.13
```

As you described, it will indeed also result in (potentially unnecessary) trailing zeroes sometimes.

```
(0.001).toFixed(2); // returns 0.00
```

You may not want to get rid of those trailing zeroes, essentially you could just convert it back to a `number`. There are many ways to do this.

```
+(0.001).toFixed(2); // the shortest
```

For an overview, of the different methods to convert strings to numbers, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227594/which-is-better-numberx-or-parsefloatx) question, which has some excellent answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use The [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method to format a number using fixed-point notation. **Keep in mind that the parameter may be a value between 0 and 20.** This returns your rounded number as a string, but it will still contain the trailing zeros. You can then use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to get your rounded number without the trailing zeros.
Examples:

```js
function prettyRound(num, decimals) {
  return parseFloat(num.toFixed(decimals));
}

const numberToRound = 1.12006
console.log(prettyRound(numberToRound, 3))

const anotherToRound = 1.10006
console.log(prettyRound(anotherToRound, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried almost all methods suggested by experts here and there.

Finally, I am satisfied with my own answer. As I came to know Math.round is more precise than .toFixed() method, I have used Math.round method.

```
Math.round(parseFloat(numberString)*100000)/100000; // to round upto 5 decimal places

Math.round(parseFloat(numberString)*1000)/1000; // to round upto 3 decimal places
```

For Example

```
  Math.round(parseFloat("1.234567")*100000)/100000 >>> 1.23457
  Math.round(parseFloat("1.234567")*1000)/1000 >>> 1.235
  Math.round(parseFloat("1.001")*100000)/100000 >>> 1.001
  Math.round(parseFloat("1.001")*1000)/1000 >>> 1.001
  Math.round(parseFloat("1.0010005")*100000)/100000 >>> 1.001
  Math.round(parseFloat("1.0010005")*1000)/1000 >>> 1.001
  Math.round(parseFloat("1.001000")*100000)/100000 >>> 1.001
  Math.round(parseFloat("1.001000")*1000)/1000 >>> 1.001
  Math.round(parseFloat("0.000100")*100000)/100000 >>> 1.0E-4
  Math.round(parseFloat("0.000100")*1000)/1000 >>> 0.0
```