# What is the difference between Unary Plus/Number(x) and parseFloat(x)?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I'm asking this just for the sake of shaving a few bytes.

I know I can use `+x` (unary plus) instead of `Number(x)`. Is there a difference between those and `parseFloat`?

Comment: @Christian: All numbers in Javascript are double precision floats.

Answer (score 427, accepted):

### The difference between parseFloat and Number

`parseFloat`/`parseInt` is for parsing a string, while `Number`/`+` is for coercing a value to a number. They behave differently. But first let's look at where they behave the same:

```
parseFloat('3'); // => 3
Number('3'); // => 3
parseFloat('1.501'); // => 1.501
Number('1.501'); // => 1.501
parseFloat('1e10'); // => 10000000000
Number('1e10'); // => 10000000000
```

So as long as you have standard numeric input, there's no difference. However, if your input starts with a number and then contains other characters, `parseFloat` truncates the number out of the string, while `Number` gives `NaN` (not a number):

```
parseFloat('1x'); // => 1
Number('1x'); // => NaN
```

In addition, `Number` understands hexadecimal input while `parseFloat` does not:

```
parseFloat('0x10'); // => 0
Number('0x10'); // => 16
```

But `Number` acts weird with empty strings or strings containing only white space:

```
parseFloat(''); // => NaN
Number(''); // => 0
parseFloat(' \r\n\t'); // => NaN
Number(' \r\n\t'); // => 0
```

On the whole, I find `Number` to be more reasonable, so I almost always use `Number` personally (and you'll find that a lot of the internal JavaScript functions use `Number` as well). If someone types `'1x'` I prefer to show an error rather than treat it as if they had typed `'1'`. The only time I really make an exception is when I am converting a style to a number, in which case `parseFloat` is helpful because styles come in a form like `'3px'`, in which case I want to drop the `'px'` part and just get the `3`, so I find `parseFloat` helpful here. But really which one you choose is up to you and which forms of input you want to accept.

Note that using the unary `+` operator is exactly the same as using `Number` as a function:

```
Number('0x10'); // => 16
+'0x10'; // => 16
Number('10x'); // => NaN
+'10x'; // => NaN
Number('40'); // => 40
+'40'; // => 40
```

So I usually just use `+` for short. As long as you know what it does, I find it easy to read.

Comment: Also calling `parseFloat` on a number converts the number first into a string and then parses that string. `Number` skips that round trip. Can there be a case where such a round trip will lose precision? I don't know.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, it appears you're right. I'm guessing I was thinking of `parseInt('1e10')` (which returns `1`) and assumed `parseFloat` behaved the same way. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: I would not consider *whitespace=>0* behaviour of `Number()` as "weird" I would even consider it as more expected, whitespace is an empty value but it is not null/undefined => 0 is a nice result. Big (+) for you for the showcases anyway :)

Comment: @NathanWall: Might want to mention that `Number('Infinity') === Infinity` whereas `parseInt('Infinity') === NaN`

Comment: I would not use `+` (unary plus) for this, because if you forget a semicolon on the previous line, an addition expression might be evaluated instead.

Comment: For the cases they behave the same I've found out that parseFloat is from 1% to 15% slower, becoming slower when the number of decimal digits in a string increases. With 1M run in my system parseFloat('1.501') is 5% slower than Number('1.501'), and parseFloat('1.50137585467') is 15% slower than Number('1.50137585467'). So, I go for Number().

Comment: @sstur This is about `parseFloat` which works fine with `'Infinity'`

Comment: @ChrisBrownie55 Wow, good catch. I didn't know parseFloat can do that. I guess Infinity is not an integer!

Comment: I like to get the best of both with `Number(parseFloat("Some number string..."))`

Answer (score 17):

The difference is what happens when the input is not a "proper number". `Number` returns `NaN` while `parseFloat` parses "as much as it can". If called on the empty string `Number` returns `0` while parseFloat returns `NaN`.

For example:

```
Number("") === 0               // also holds for false
isNaN(parseFloat("")) === true // and null

isNaN(Number("32f")) === true
parseFloat("32f") === 32
```

Comment: Note that `NaN != NaN` though

Comment: @Wex Oh you ment that `NaN != NaN` evaluates to **TRUE** - thanks for the tip !

Comment: use **isNaN()** for testing the NaN value, `isNaN(NaN)` returns `true`

Answer (score 16):

In these examples you can see the difference:

```
Number('') = 0;
Number(false) = 0;
Number('1a') = NaN;

parseFloat('') = NaN;
parseFloat(false) = NaN;
parseFloat('1a') = 1;
```

parseFloat is a bit slower because it searches for first appearance of a number in a string, while the Number constuctor creates a new number instance from strings that contains numeric values with whitespace or that contains falsy values.

Answer (score 2):

For empty string, they are different.

`+""` and `Number("")` returns 0, while `parseFloat("")` returns NaN.

Comment: I would go so far as to say that `parseFloat()` has the right result as an empty string is NOT the number `0` (read: NaN) while a string with the character `"0"` in it IS `0`;

Comment: `+x` returns `0` not only for an empty string but also for any whitespace-only strings. Examples: `+"        "`, `+"\t\t\t"`, `+"\n\n"` - all of them give `0` as result

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, and this is only overheard from colleagues so might be entirely ill informed, that parseFloat is marginally faster.

Though on further researching, it would seem that this performance difference is browser dependant.

http://jsperf.com/parseint-vs-parsefloat/6

Have a look at these jsPerf results, and make you're call. (it includes +x tests as well)

As noted in @xdazz 's answer, `+""` and `Number("")` return `0` while `parseFloat("")` returns `NaN` so Again I would go with parseFloat, because an empty string does NOT mean the number 0, only a string with the character `"0"` in it means 0;

Comment: Here's a [more exhaustive test](http://jsperf.com/implicit-vs-explicit-string-to-float-conversion) fishing for a faster way to convert... `parseFloat()` is still the winner.