# + operator vs parseFloat

Tags: javascript

[Example 1](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) of the knockout extenders page describes a way of rounding user input and making sure it is only numeric.

It works great, but looking through the source they do a peculiar thing that i don't understand, that is on line 8 they do this:

```
parseFloat(+newValue)
```

`newValue` is a string.

When i initially asked this question I didn't know what `+` did - some further [poking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227594/which-is-better-numberx-or-parsefloatx) and a [link to a different MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) from one of the initial answers I got indicate it is a unary operator equivalent to `number(str)` and that there are some differences between `+str` and `parseFloat(str)` (treatment of strings ending in alpha characters and interpretation of hex seem to be the headlines).

I still don't understand why the `+` in this case needed to be wrapped in the `parseFloat` although I am starting to think it might be a typo...

Comment: I just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227594/which-is-better-numberx-or-parsefloatx question which is similar - the answerers explanation of the differences between parseFloat and + are pretty good. But it still doesn't explain why the number should be parsed afterwards...

Comment: It simply makes no sense to use both. Calling `parseFloat` on a number is an antipattern.

Comment: Can you limit your question to #2?

Comment: Thanks Bergi - I don't think i makes any sense either...

Comment: The line in question seems equivalent to `+newValue || 0`

Comment: No, `parseFloat` is not equivalent to `|| 0`. It still yields `NaN` for example

Comment: sorry, you are quite right - i was referring to the entire thing in the original example - i.e. `isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : parseFloat(+newValue)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is better, number(x) or parseFloat(x)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227594/which-is-better-numberx-or-parsefloatx)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Citing MDN docs for [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

> `parseFloat` parses its argument, a string, and returns a floating point number. If it encounters a character other than a sign (+ or -), numeral (0-9), a decimal point, or an exponent, **it returns the value up to that point and ignores that character and all succeeding characters. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.**

Using [unary plus operator][2] you may be sure that `parseFloat` operates on `Number`, which is only useful if you want to be more strict about results but still want to use a `parseFloat`

```
parseFloat('0.32abcd') // -> 0.32
parseFloat(+'0.32abcd') // -> NaN
```


**Update:**

After a bit of digging in docs and running some tests, seems there is no reason to use `parseFloat` other than parsing strings that may contain numbers with non numeric trails to number, eq:

```
parseFloat('31.5 miles') // -> 31.5
parseFloat('12.75em') // -> 12.75
```

For any other cases where your string contains number `+` is a *fastest and prefered* way (citing [MDN docs for unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus)):

> unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number, because it does not perform any other operations on the number.

See [parseFloat versus unary test case](http://jsperf.com/parsefloat-versus-unary/3) for how faster it is.

Previous link broken so [here is the new test](https://jsben.ch/T7P7I) that shows how unary is faster.

Comment: Sure, but why is `parseFloat(+'0.32abcd')` different from `+'0.32abcd'`?

Comment: what do you cite? How does that answer the questions?

Comment: @Bergi, I'm citing MDN. Added reference and bit explanation

Comment: But parseFloat is supposed to operate on a string - why would you want it to operate on a number?

Comment: @JoshWallace, because it's not strict enough. BTW, MDN describe this behavior and also provide sample for a [stricter parse function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat#A_stricter_parse_function)

Comment: @JuicyScripter But that MDN page is addressing a different problem and describing how to use regexp. In this case, I still don't understand why the `parseFloat` is necessary and what value it adds. Can you please try to explain that clearly, and give an example of a case where `+xxxxx` means something different from `parseFloat(+xxxxx)`?

Comment: @torazaburo, where is no real reason to use `parseFloat(+xxx)` it's just pure overhead. See my updated answer.

Comment: late to the party, but just wanted to add that null handling and empty strings should also be considered -- eg ```parseFloat(null)``` is NaN but ```+null``` is 0.  Depending on what you are doing this might be unexpected behavior