# How to keep value as number in JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing, numbers

I'm trying to use `JSON.stringify()` to parse some values into JSON format. That `amount` is a string variable.I want the final value in JSON format as a number, but my current way doesn't work. It still comes out as `"price":"1.00"` after `JSON.stringify()` . How do I make sure the final value in JSON is a number? Thanks for your help!

My current code:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
 "payer": "a cat",     
 "price": parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2),

});
```

Comment: So why are you converting it to a string with toFixed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`toFixed` returns a string. If you want to output a number, just use `parseFloat`:

```
JSON.stringify({
  "payer": "a cat",
  "price": parseFloat(amount)
});
```

I don't think there's a way to output a number to any precision after the decimal without converting it to a string.

Comment: Or just `+amount`.

Comment: multiply, floor/round/ceil, divide

Answer (score 4):

I think Number() will work too

The differences are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227594/which-is-better-numberx-or-parsefloatx). I have worked with both in JSON.stringify

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "payer": "a cat",
  "price": Number(amount)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, creating random float number, this is my solution:

```
// Create a random float number between 10 and 120, with only 2 decimal place
var number = Math.floor((Math.random()*110+10)*100)/100
```

So is still a floating value, with 2 decimal place, also after JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 0):

This way has served me.

```
function replace(key, value) {
  if (typeof value != "object") {
    let change = parseFloat(value);
    return change;
  }
  return value;
}

const msg = JSON.stringify(params, replace);`
```

Params is a variable that contains a query parameter.

Comment: Won't this try to convert every string to float, whether the string contains a number or not?

Comment: Yes. In case you want to avoid that, you should add another validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => {
    if (!isNaN(value))
        value = Number(value)
    return value
})
```