# JSON.stringify() function in JSR223post processor to capture the response in jmeter. but it is trimming the decimal points from the response

Tags: json, jmeter, jsr223

i am using JSON.stringify() function in JSR223post processor to capture the response in jmeter. but it is trimming the decimal points from the response.

suppose Quanity: 120.000 will be there in actual response but my function is taking only 120. could anyone help on this

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624332/how-to-keep-value-as-number-in-json-stringify

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep value as number in JSON.stringify()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624332/how-to-keep-value-as-number-in-json-stringify)

Answer (score 0):

1. Looking into [JSON.stringify() function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it doesn't seem that you can control the way of numeric values serialization
2. [Using JavaScript is kind of a performance anti-pattern](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), you should be using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), take a look at [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) article

   [image]

If you have to use JavaScript for any reason you can try [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) functions

[image]