# parseFloat with characters after number

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

I have an input where the user introduces a number, integer or float. I would like to know it the number is correct, for example, check that the input `2r` is not correct. My first approach was to use `parseFloat`, but it does not complain about that:

```
parseFloat('2r')   // returns 2
```

Actually, this is the expected behaviour according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

How do you check that `2r` is wrong?

Answer (score 6):

This is not an error with `parseFloat`, seems like you are after something else.

Try Number;

```js
Number('2r'); // returns Nan
```

Comment: Thx. That was, what I need. Discussion between `Number` and `parseFloat` goes on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227594/which-is-better-numberx-or-parsefloatx

Answer (score 2):

It ls [well documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

> If parseFloat encounters a character other than a plus sign (+), minus
>   sign (- U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS), numeral (0–9), decimal point (.), or
>   exponent (e or E), it returns the value up to that character, ignoring
>   the invalid character and characters following it.

The following examples all return 3.14:

```
parseFloat(3.14);
parseFloat('3.14');
parseFloat('  3.14  ');
parseFloat('314e-2');
parseFloat('0.0314E+2');
parseFloat('3.14some non-digit characters');
parseFloat({ toString: function() { return "3.14" } });
```

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behaviour - parseFloat and similar will ignore any 'junk' following a real number.

If you need to verify that this is a real number as a whole, then there are various strategies to use, the easiest of which is to try a mathematical operation, such as multiplying by one.

Comment: `'2r' + 0` just results in `'2r0'`...

Comment: As Mike said, this is the expected behavior.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat.  Use the Number() function for stricter parsing as noted in this reference.

Comment: parseFloat('2r' + 0) returns 2 again

Comment: Sorry, miss remembered that - parseFloat('2r' * 1)  gives NaN