# How to add a value in array of JSON objects on javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array json object called payment

```
[ { billed : "100", owed: "50" }, { billed : "200", owed: "100" }]
```

I want to sum up "billed" field and net answer should be 300.
I tried the following:

```
let    paidPaymentCents = 0;   
for (let payment in payments) {
          paidPaymentCents += payments[payment].billed;
}
```

Is there any better way using reduce : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: What is `0l` please?

Comment: What is `payments` and what is `amountPaidCents`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript's [reduce()](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) would be the method for this. Once the `JSON` is parsed and you have an array or objects:

```
let testAry = [{ billed : "100", owed: "50" }, { billed : "200", owed: "100" }],
    amt = testAry
          // 1. isolate and parse
          .map(item => parseFloat(item.billed))
          // 2. add up all billed
          .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(amt)
```

Depending on the consistency of the data, you might want to use `Number` instead of `parseFloat`. More here: [parseFloat vs Number](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

You can make it smaller (thanks @Devon):

```
 .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + parseFloat(curr.billed), 0)
```

Comment: You could even eliminate the map in the chain by doing: `.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + parseFloat(curr.billed), 0)`

Answer (score 2):

You could do this very easily using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Within the reduce, you can treat each `element.billed` as a number instance by wrapping it with [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). You would start with `0` as your accumulator and add each `element.billed` to get the total. Here is an example:

```js
const data = [{
  billed: "100",
  owed: "50"
}, {
  billed: "200",
  owed: "100"
}];


const total = data.reduce((runningTotal, element) => {
  runningTotal += Number(element.billed);

  return runningTotal;
}, 0);

console.log(`Total billed amount is ${total}`);
```

Comment: Based on this answer, why would I use `Number`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227594/which-is-better-numberx-or-parsefloatx

Answer (score 1):

Each of the payment object in the loop has the structure `{ billed : "100", owed: "50" }`

So you can do

```
let payments = [ { billed : "100", owed: "50" }, { billed : "200", owed: "100" }]
let    paidPaymentCents = 0;  
for (var i = 0;i < payments.length; i++) {
    paidPaymentCents += Number(payments[i].billed);
}
```

And you will have the `paidPaymentCents` will have the total.