# LightningChart JS crashes with t.toFixed is not a function

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am using a LightningChart JS by Arction to plot a bar graph and it keeps crashing after adding the rectangle figures with an error message: `t.toFixed is not a function`

The series being used is a rectangle series and I'd like to use only one rectangle series because I need them all under one group.

Below is my code

```js
// Core react imports
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
// React bootstrap imports
import { Col } from "react-bootstrap"
// Chart imports
import {
    lightningChart,
    SolidFill,
    SolidLine,
    emptyTick,
    emptyLine,
    FontSettings,
    ColorHEX,
} from "@arction/lcjs"
import axios from "axios"
export default function Histogram() {
    const createChart = useCallback(
        () => {

            const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({ containerId: "myplot" });
            chart
                .setTitle("RR Histogram")
                .setTitleFillStyle((solidFill) => solidFill.setColor(ColorHEX("#000")))
                .setTitleMarginTop(0)
                .setTitleMarginBottom(0)
                .setChartBackgroundFillStyle((solidFill) =>
                    solidFill.setColor(ColorHEX("#FFF"))
                )
                .setBackgroundFillStyle((solidFill) =>
                    solidFill.setColor(ColorHEX("#FFF"))
                )
                .setZoomingRectangleStrokeStyle(
                    new SolidLine({
                        fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX("#000") }),
                    })
                )
                .setTitleFont(new FontSettings({ size: 20 }));
            // Configure X-axis of chart to be progressive and have nice interval.
            chart
                .getDefaultAxisX();
            // .setTickStyle(emptyTick)
            // .setNibStyle(emptyLine)
            // .setTitleFont(new FontSettings({ size: 12 }))
            // .setStrokeStyle(emptyLine);
            chart
                .getDefaultAxisY();
            // .setTickStyle(emptyTick)
            // .setNibStyle(emptyLine)
            // .setStrokeStyle(emptyLine);
            let rectSeries = chart
                .addRectangleSeries()
                .setDefaultStyle(figure => figure.setFillStyle(new SolidFill({
                    color: ColorHEX("#000")
                })));
            let rr_hist = {};
            axios
                .get("Api  url here")
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res)
                    rr_hist = res.data;
                })
                .catch((err) => console.log(err));
            setTimeout(() => {
                for (let point in rr_hist) {
                    let insert_Point = {
                        height: rr_hist[point],
                        y: 0,
                        x: point,
                        width: 1
                    }
                    let bar = rectSeries.add(insert_Point);
                    bar.setDimensions(insert_Point);
                    bar.setFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX("#000") }));
                    bar.setStrokeStyle(new SolidLine({
                        fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX("#000") }),
                    }))
                }
                console.log(rr_hist)
            }, 2000)
        },
        [],
    )
    useEffect(() => {
        createChart()
    }, [createChart])
    return (
        <Col xs={12} style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>
            <div id="myplot" style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}></div>
        </Col>
    )
}
```

Also could you please let me know how to improve the styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely reason for the crash is that your `height` or `x` field for the new rectangle figure is not a number. LightningChart JS doesn't do type conversions for input values.

So when adding new rectangles to rectangle series make sure to do the type conversion from string to number yourself.

```js
let insert_Point = {
    height: Number(rr_hist[point]),
    y: 0,
    x: Number(point),
    width: 1
}
let bar = rectSeries.add(insert_Point);
```

Instead of using `Number` for the conversion you could use `parseFloat` or `parseInt` depending on the type of data you use. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13676265/6198227 that answer for more detailed differences between `Number` and `parseFloat`.

For styling, it looks like you would benefit from using a light colored theme. When creating the chart with [`ChartXY`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/interfaces/lightningchart.html#chartxy) you can specify `theme` option.

```js
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
    theme: Themes.light
})
```

You can see the available themes in our docs [`Themes`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/globals.html#themes)