# Converting numerical string using parseInt() and parseFloat() results in wrong conversion

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know what's causing this error when converting a string of "1.14" to a number?

And most importantly, how to eliminate any risk of incorrect conversions like this one:

```
console.log(parseInt(parseFloat("1.14") * 100) / 100); // prints 1.13 instead of 1.14
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(Number("1.14") * 100 / 100);
```

Your issue will be resolved by applying this solution for more detail you can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227594/which-is-better-numberx-or-parsefloatx)