# Convert javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

Please help me transform the object. I have an object of the form

```
const object = {
  2021: {
    "13.0": { data: {} },
    "13.1": { data: {} },
    "17.0": { data: {} },
    "17.1": { data: {} },
  },
  2022: {
    "13.0": { data: {} },
    "13.1": { data: {} },
    "17.0": { data: {} },
    "17.1": { data: {} },
  },
};
```

If the number ends with ".0", then I need to change the number to a format without zero at the end of the number. The result should be an object of the form

```
const obj1 = {
  2021: {
    "13": { data: {} },
    "13.1": { data: {} },
    "17": { data: {} },
    "17.1": { data: {} },
  },
  2022: {
    "13": { data: {} },
    "13.1": { data: {} },
    "17": { data: {} },
    "17.1": { data: {} },
  },
};
```

I wrote the following code

```
const obj1 = {};

for (let year in object) {
  obj1[year] = object[year];

  for (let number in object[year]) {
    const keyOk = number.endsWith('.0')
      ? number.slice(0, number.length - 2)
      : number;

    obj1[year][keyOk] = object[year][number];
    if (number.endsWith('.0')) {
      delete object[year][number];
    }
  }
}
```

This code works, but it seems to me that this option is not the most beautiful in terms of execution. Please tell me how else can I do this? Thank you

Comment: code review maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse each key as a number (using `parseFloat(x)` or `+x`) and assign that as the key of the new object. This will remove ".0", ".00", etc from the key.

```js
const object = {
  '2021': {
    '13.0': {
      data: {},
    },
    '13.1': {
      data: {},
    },
    '17.0': {
      data: {},
    },
    '17.1': {
      data: {},
    },
  },
  '2022': {
    '13.0': {
      data: {},
    },
    '13.1': {
      data: {},
    },
    '17.0': {
      data: {},
    },
    '17.1': {
      data: {},
    },
  },
}

const obj1 = {}

for (let year in object) {
  obj1[year] = {}
  for (let number in object[year]) {
    // We convert `number` to a number and use that as the new key, to remove unnecessary ".0".
    obj1[year][+number] = object[year][number]
  }
}

console.log(obj1)
```

Output:

```
{
  "2021": {
    "13": {
      "data": {}
    },
    "17": {
      "data": {}
    },
    "13.1": {
      "data": {}
    },
    "17.1": {
      "data": {}
    }
  },
  "2022": {
    "13": {
      "data": {}
    },
    "17": {
      "data": {}
    },
    "13.1": {
      "data": {}
    },
    "17.1": {
      "data": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @pilchard thanks, you're right, I've fixed the alternate suggestion. `+x` is closer to `parseFloat(x)` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227594/what-is-the-difference-between-unary-plus-numberx-and-parsefloatx) which is why my code was working.

Answer (score 1):

To remove unnecessary zeros, you can parse the string with `parseFloat()`,

```
var n = "13.50";
    n = parseFloat(n); // 13.5
```

> The parseFloat function converts its first argument to a `string`,
> parses that string as a `decimal` number literal, then returns a number
> or `NaN`.

More description can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, you can use parseFloat on the keys and then turn them into strings to get rid of any unnecessary decimal points. If the data structure stays the same, you can simply use the following code:

```
const obj1 = {};
for (const year in obj) {
    obj1[year] = {};
    for (const numStr in obj[year]) {
        const newNumStr = parseFloat(numStr).toString();
        obj1[year][newNumStr] = obj[year][numStr];
    }
}
```