# Limit results on 2 decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal, limit

I have this script:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        var total_share = $('.irpg_totalcount .irpg_t_nb').text();
        var total_share = parseFloat(total_share);
        if(total_share==0) { total_share = 1; }
        var value_share = 1000 / total_share;
        $('.share_info span').text(value_share);
    }, 3000);

});
```

Some results displaying for example:

3333.333333333

How to limited results on two decimal?

Comment: try this `3333.333333333.toFixed(2);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Round to a number of decimal places, but strip extra zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312468/javascript-round-to-a-number-of-decimal-places-but-strip-extra-zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use `.toFixed(2)` method in javascript

```
$('.share_info span').text(parseFloat(value_share).toFixed(2))
```

Comment: @BracaCobra can you use fire bug from Mozilla and what are error paste here

Comment: Can you take a look here:[link]http://irishpropertygroup.com/property/denmark-street/  on the middle page.

Comment: `parse_Float` is not a function

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement   $('.share_info span').text(value_share).toFixed(2));

Comment: @BracaCobra change that line to this `$('.share_info span').text(parseFloat(value_share).toFixed(2));`

Comment: @BracaCobra always use `alert('your code');` for testing in javascript and Dont forgot to mark it as answer

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is my first time on StackOverFlow. Nice expirience!

Answer (score 1):

Use [toFixed()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) javascript function like this:

```
newResult = result.toFixed(2);
```

result = the initial result with multiple decimals

newResult = the desired result (2 decimals)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toFixed`.

> The toFixed() method converts a number into a string, keeping a
>   specified number of decimals.

```
var num = 3333.333333333     
var n = num.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Examples for [**toFixed**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var numObj = 12345.6789;

numObj.toFixed();       // Returns '12346': note rounding, no fractional part
numObj.toFixed(1);      // Returns '12345.7': note rounding
numObj.toFixed(6);      // Returns '12345.678900': note added zeros
(1.23e+20).toFixed(2);  // Returns '123000000000000000000.00'
(1.23e-10).toFixed(2);  // Returns '0.00'
2.34.toFixed(1);        // Returns '2.3'
-2.34.toFixed(1);       // Returns -2.3 (due to operator precedence, negative number literals don't return a string...)
(-2.34).toFixed(1);     // Returns '-2.3' (...unless you use parentheses)
```