# Round a number down in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I know this maybe very simple and common but I want to know about this calculation:

Example: I have a decimal number `4.716981132075472`, but I only need the `4` number, is there any calculation able to do this?

Comment: You always want to round down? `Math.floor(number)`?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312468/javascript-round-to-a-number-of-decimal-places-but-strip-extra-zeros ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try round off:

```
var result = 4.716981132075472 << 0;
alert(result);
```

OR

```
var result = Math.floor(4.716981132075472);
alert(result);
```

Comment: the first option its really cool.. what the name for do that??

Comment: @ncubica, `<<` a left-shift bitwise operator

Comment: Or `var result = 4.716981132075472 | 0;`

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `Math.floor()` [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FMath%2Ffloor)

Comment: MDN is great, but the definitive documentation is here: [*ECMA-262 §15.8.2.9*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.9). :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try `Math.floor( 4.716981132075472);`. This rounds the number down to the nearest integer, thus solving your problem.