# Why is one form input constantly being treated as a string?

Tags: javascript

This is a pretty basic `SIP` calculator that should not take more than 5 lines. But the variable amount is constantly being treated as a `string`. I have to keep using `parseFloat()` and declare three additional variables to store the final values before returning them for the code to work. Is there any workaround?

```js
function sipCalculator(amount, r, n) {
  r = r / 12;
  amount = parseFloat(amount);
  var temp = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    temp += amount;
    temp += (temp * (r / 100));
  }
  var x = amount * n;
  var y = parseFloat(temp.toFixed(2));
  var z = parseFloat((y - x).toFixed(2));
  return [x, y, z];
};
```

Comment: How do you call the function? As in what parameters are you passing? Also, `.toFixed(2)` converts the number to a string, if you aren't already aware.

Comment: `amount` would only be a string if it's passed in as a string. Other than that, `toFixed` returns a string. So I'm not sure how the variable treated as a string when it shouldn't.

Comment: If amount is an `input`'s value it will always be a string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML input type="number" still returning a string when accessed from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791767/html-input-type-number-still-returning-a-string-when-accessed-from-javascript) and [Input value is a string instead of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849944)

Comment: @Nisarg I know, that's why I am using parseFloat()

Answer (score 1):

The call to `.toFixed(2)` is converting the numbers to a string. If you instead want them to be numbers, while limiting them up to two decimal places, then [`parseFloat(num.toFixed(2))` is the recommended approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7312534/5894241) (which you are already doing).

Here's MDN's documentation on `Number.prototype.toFixed`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

---

If you just don't like the verbosity of `parseFloat`, [you can use `+` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133814/5894241) to convert the string to a number. *Of course that's not the best idea as not everyone would know what it does.*

```js
var x = 1.44444;
console.log(+x.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with what I am already doing? I guess this is an issue with the input tag that I am using to get the data.

Comment: @Tethys_94 Yup, sort of. Basically when you read value of an text input, it will always be a string. So to get a number, you have to use `parseFloat`. Same goes for `.toFixed`. It is not wrong as long as it is a requirement.

Comment: You can't store a numeric value with 2 fraction digits. The number is always rounded (with some exceptions) to the nearest possible value. Exceptions are numbers like 0.50 0.25 0.125 0.375. That's the reason, that toFixed() returns a string.

Comment: @wimm I don't understand your point in the context of this question. OP is not asking **why** `toFixed` returns a string.